# How do I determine a student's graduation in C++?

Tags: c++

Requirements are the average of 3 scores must be more than 70, and 2 of those scores must be more than 60.

Here's the code I have currently.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  float x,y,z,avg;
  cout << "1:";
  cin >> x;
  cout << "2:";
  cin >> y;
  cout << "3:";
  cin >> z;
  avg = (x+y+z)/3;

  if (avg > 70) 
  cout << "You passed.";
  else 
  cout << "You didn't pass.";
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's the code you have, yes. What about the other question? What have tried so far to solve it? What failed? And what is you question? Maybe that's also helpful to guide you: [How do I ask (and answer) homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: And... what your problem is?

Comment: Looks like you need a few more conditions in the `if` statement (or another `if` statement). Think it out on paper, and when the paper version looks like it works, code it and see if the computer agrees.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check that at least 2 scores are higher than 60 then just add `((x > 60) + (y > 60) + (z > 60) >= 2)` to the condition. Each comparison that is `true` will return 1, but if it is `false` it will return 0. Then 2 or 3 of the conditions must be `true` to the total expresion to be `true`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  float x,y,z,avg;
  cout << "1:";
  cin >> x;
  cout << "2:";
  cin >> y;
  cout << "3:";
  cin >> z;
  avg = (x+y+z)/3;

  if (avg > 70 && ((x > 60) + (y > 60) + (z > 60) >= 2))
    cout << "You passed.";
  else
    cout << "You didn't pass.";
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: How does this code resolve the OP's issue?  Please don't post code without annotations or descriptions on how it resolves the OP's issue.